# Can a business reimburse travel booked with award miles?

Tags: irs, travel, reimbursement, frequent-flier-miles

We have an employee who booked business travel using a combination of credit card (cash) and his award miles (Chase points). He is now requesting a reimbursement of the full cash ***value*** of the tickets ($2700), not what was paid on his card for the tickets ($2400).

Is this legal/permissible by the IRS tax code?

Comment: I'm certain that paying the employee $2700 is permissible. Whether you can classify it as completely a reimbursement and not just an extra payment for the IRS is less easy to ascertain. As the question is stated, the answer is "yes".  The question really is whether the $300 is taxable extra income or not. That, I don't know. :-)

Comment: Time to update your travel reimbursement policy!

Comment: Thanks @PeterK. you are right, the second question of whether the extra $300 is taxable income is something we would really like to find out!

Comment: @MarkStewart indeed ;) We are refining our policy as soon as we get this tracked down!

Comment: Sounds like stealing...

Comment: I think I'd fire him for being dumb enough to use Award Miles instead of getting the $2700 from you and then the Bonus Points converted to cash.  If it's a Chase Freedom Unlimited, that's $40.50.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If self-employed, only the $2400 could be claimed as business expense, the $300 is a discount on a service so would have no bearing on taxes one way or the other.

I'm confident in the claim above, pretty confident too that if you choose to reimburse the employee $2700, only $2400 is expense reimbursement, $300 is pay subject to income tax, they are making money on this transaction as points aren't money.

The closest IRS source I could find is [IRS Publication 463](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p463.pdf), which states:

> IF you have expenses for transportation then you can deduct the cost
>   of...
>  travel by airplane, train, bus, or car between your home and
>   your business destination. If you were provided with a free ticket or
>   you are riding free as a result of a frequent traveler or similar
>   program, your cost is zero. If you travel by ship, see Luxury Water
>   Travel and Cruise Ships, under Conventions, earlier, for additional
>   rules and limits.

While it doesn't explicitly mention partial payments via reward, the concept is similar, you can't claim an expense for which there was no actual cost. Similarly you can't claim charitable contribution for donated points. Conversely an individual isn't taxed on points received, you just can't double-dip by claiming an expense for which there was no actual cost.

There are gobs of non-IRS sources that indicate inability to deduct rewards purchases as business expenses, I'm sure an accountant type can give a more technical and complete answer.

Comment: Thanks. You would happen to know which point of the IRS code references this topic specifically?

Comment: The question didn't ask about tax deduction tho. It asked about reimbursement policy.

Comment: @WakeDemons3 Expense reimbursements are tied to deductible expenses, ie you can't call an employee's wage an expense reimbursement  (effectively dodging payroll taxes) per the IRS, so if they want to pay this person the full claimed amount, they'll have to call a portion of it a bonus or some such, as I mention.

Comment: While you are likely correct that the IRS would not consider this an expense, it is simply not true that there is not a cost. An opportunity cost is still a cost. Miles are a valuable asset, and losing them is a cost.

Comment: @Acccumulation Very true, the IRS cares not about opportunity cost.